# Hallel Grammar בתוכך vs בְּתוֹכֵכִי

Tags: grammar-dikduk, hallel

Why do some chazanim pronounce בתוכך during Hallel instead of בְּתוֹכֵכִי - the way it's written in the pasuk?

> [116:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b6.htm) בְּחַצְרוֹת, בֵּית יְהוָה--    **בְּתוֹכֵכִי** יְרוּשָׁלִָם:
> הַלְלוּ-יָהּ. In the courts of the LORD'S house, in the midst of thee, O Jerusalem. Hallelujah.

Although I heard Rav Reisman mention that tehillim takes liberties with certain grammatical rules, I don't understand why that would give chazanim the liberty to say the words differently.

**Note:** I heard these different chazanim in an Ashkenaz shul in Lakewood (Rav of the shul is a renowned posek) and a nusach-sefard shul in NJ (Rav of the shul is also a respected posek)

Comment: Maybe they're reading it wrong?

Comment: Have you asked those chazanim?

Comment: Which chazzanim are these? Are they of a particular background or affiliation?

Comment: Good points - edited in the question. Still, these chazanim are themselves learned individuals. Although I first thought it was a mistake, hearing it done in more frum Jewish communities made me wonder...

Comment: Might they just be slurring 'tokhekhi' and 'yerushalayim'?

Comment: @mevaqesh My wife suggested the same thing (of course she's right), but the fact this issue spans different shuls, cities, and ashkenaz vs sefard makes it a little more than coincidence...or not.